# MVC4 Model DefaultValue namespace?

Tags: model, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-4

What namespace should I be using to use [DefaultValue(true)] in my MVC4 model ?

Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) - `using System.ComponentModel`